# Will a warm body naturally slowdown?

Tags: special-relativity, vacuum, thermal-radiation, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

Suppose a warm body moving in an empty space with high speed.

The body emits radiation based on its temperature. The protons emitted forwards of the body will have higher energy due to Doppler shift than those emitted backwards. Thus they will care greater momentum. The body should slowdown due to emitted radiation.

Is there a mistake in this reasoning? Possibly the number of photons emitted forwards will be smaller?

Comment: Your reasoning looks fine.. No, the number of photons should stay the same in all directions for a symmetric body. I'm not too sure about this, though; there may be some quantum effects involved. If you're looking at this from the Gallileo point of view (Body in motion in vacuum stays in motion), then the flaw in using this is that there is a net force on the body, as loss of photons $\implies$ change in momentum $\implies$ force (though this comes from Newton). Rockets work on the same principle (they lose mass through their jets).

Comment: The doppler effect is an observer-dependent effect. If this actually happened, it would violate relativity.

Comment: zephyr, indeed but lets consider a rest frame relative to which the warm body moves.

Comment: @Anixx, then you could equally well consider a frame in which the body moves the opposite direction. Obviously the effect there should be equal and opposite, and something can't slow down in two different directions!

Comment: Indeed. That is why my question. How this paradox is resolved.

Comment: @Anixx a somewhat similar situation does occur when an object moves relative to a thermal radiation bath like the cosmic microwave background - then doppler shifted absorption can slow its relative motion.

Comment: @Anixx there is no paradox if you stop thinking that the photons emitted are doppler shifted. Doppler shift is a phenomenon that occurs for the observer in relative motion.

Comment: Yes. In that case we should observe an actual slowdown.

Comment: They are doppler-shifted in the rest frame. This shift can be measured.

Comment: No, if you are in a frame which is not moving relative to the emitter, they are not shifted.

Comment: If not moving, not shifted, if moving, then shifted...

Comment: Anixx, do you understand what a rest frame is?

Comment: Here's something that may clarify a few things. Lets say you have a normal ball at 0K, which ic capable of symmetrically and slowly turning from mass to energy at your command (by this, i mean that the energy is uniformly released from all sides, and the mass gradually decomposes). You set it in motion, and then tell it to go boom. In your frame, something with a forward momentum p has become a bunch of light. This light must have a net forward momentum p. The mechanism may be due to (relativistic) doppler effect, or maybe something else, but the light emitted must have a net forward momentum.

Comment: Now, relate my situation with yours. The method of radiation of light is the same, thus it must have a net forward momentum. So yes, the ball *_must slow down_. By what mechanism and by how much is something which I don't have the time to ponder right now.

Comment: Well, indeed you are right. Now it's clear. The warm body will cool and loose its mass. Its momentum will also decrease but the body will not slow down because its mass will decrease as well.

Comment: No, it seems it will not slow down even though it will loose the momentum. It will have lesser momentum and lesser mass but the same speed.

Comment: @Anixx It will not lose mass. My example body loses mass, but here I was only comparing the method of radiation of energy (which is the same), and not effects to the body (which are different). In my example, the body indeed slowly loses mass, and thus it may or may not slow down (will require calculation). In your original question, there is a loss of forward momentum (as the method of radiation--uniform--is the same as in my example), but no loss in mass. There is instead a corresponding decrease in thermal energy.

Comment: Decrease in thermal energy means loss of the total mass of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is that the body will indeed loose the momentum. But since the mass of the body will decrease as well due to radiation, the velocity should not change.

Comment: Uhh, how exactly will the mass decrease?  A body that cools down does not lose mass (in the classical sense). The photons are created by a decrease in thermal energy of the body.

Comment: Loosing energy it will decrease its total inertial mass. Because thermal energy has mass of its own. The total momentum of energy (thermal+radiation) will not change.

Comment: Thats why I said 'in the classical sense' im neglecting relativity. Oh! I got the solution now... I'll post it as an answer..

Comment: Relativity should not be neglected here because the radiation carries some momentum. If to conut the momentum carried by radiation, one should also count the momentum carried by the thermal energy inside the body.

Comment: The momentum carried by radiation is a quantum mechanical effect, not a relativistic effect. But you're right, we cannot neglect relativity. I'm posting it as an answer (will take 10 mins, not doing this from a pc), as its a bit long.

Comment: What is more important one should not neglect the momentum carried by thermal energy. All is clear for me by now. No need for additional answers.

Comment: Now you tell me... After I typed the whole thing on a phone :P. Anyways, there's one more thing in that answer which you may have been neglecting (though it will only be required if you're trying to actually prove this quantitatively). Basically you neglected the relativistic doppler effect, too (see above answer).

Comment: This answer should not have been down-voted. It is correct. The thermal energy stored in the body makes a contribution to its mass (via $E=mc^2$), and when it loses this energy to radiation this reduces its momentum without changing its speed. Momentum is transferred from the body to the radiation field, but the body's velocity remains constant in all reference frames.

Comment: @Manishearth I'm pretty sure the momentum carried by radiation is neither a quantum mechanical effect nor a relativistic one. As far as I know it can be derived from Maxwell's equations alone. (Planck knew about the formula for radiation pressure before he derived his formula for black body radiation, from which quantum mechanics eventually developed. The ability of radiation to transfer momentum follows from its ability to exert pressure.)

Answer (score 2):

The  apparent paradox can be analyzed more clearly if we simplify it a bit. Let's assume we have one object with mass $M$ emitting two photons in opposite directions, each of them with momentum $p$.

In the rest frame of the object, choosing the X-axis to align with the emitted photons, we will have the following [four-momenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) (using units where $c = 1$):

**Before**

$p_{obj}^{before} = [M,0,0,0]$

**After**

$p_{obj}^{after} = [M-2p,0,0,0]$

$p_{\gamma_1} = [p,p,0,0]$

$p_{\gamma_2} = [p,-p,0,0]$

Here we clearly have four-momentum conservation:

$p_{obj}^{before} = p_{obj}^{after} + p_{\gamma_1} + p_{\gamma_2}$

As this is a Lorentz-invariant four-vector equation, it will be valid in any reference frame.

To see it more explicitly, [let's boost the system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformations#Boost_in_the_x-direction) by a speed $v$ in the +X direction and see how the equations look then:

**Before**

$p_{obj}^{before} = \left[M\,(1-v^2)^{-1/2},M\,v\,(1-v^2)^{-1/2},0,0\right]$

**After**

$p_{obj}^{after} = \left[(M-2p)\,(1-v^2)^{-1/2},(M-2p)\,v\,(1-v^2)^{-1/2},0,0\right]$

$p_{\gamma_1} = \left[p(1-v^2)^{-1/2}+p\,v\,(1-v^2)^{-1/2},p(1-v^2)^{-1/2}+p\,v\,(1-v^2)^{-1/2},0,0\right]$

$p_{\gamma_1} = \left[p(1+v)(1-v^2)^{-1/2},p(1+v)(1-v^2)^{-1/2},0,0\right]$

$p_{\gamma_2} = \left[p(1-v)(1-v^2)^{-1/2},p(1-v)(1-v^2)^{-1/2},0,0\right]$

Here it's a bit more tedious, though straightforward, to check four-momentum conservation.

To finish the analysis, let's see how the X component of the photon momentum is transformed when we boost the system. We start by adding back the powers of $c$:

$p^{boosted}_{\gamma_1x} = p\left(1+\frac{v}{c}\right)\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}$

Using [the relationship between wavelength and momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Physical_properties) and doing some algebra,

$\lambda^{boosted}_{\gamma_1} = h\left(\frac{h}{\lambda^{unboosted}_{\gamma_1}}\left(1+\frac{v}{c}\right)\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}\right)^{-1}$

$\lambda^{boosted}_{\gamma_1} = \lambda^{unboosted}_{\gamma_1}\left(1+\beta\right)^{-1}\left(1-\beta^2\right)^{1/2}$

$\lambda^{boosted}_{\gamma_1} = \lambda^{unboosted}_{\gamma_1}\left(1+\beta\right)^{-1}\left(1+\beta\right)^{1/2}\left(1-\beta\right)^{1/2}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\lambda^{boosted}_{\gamma_1}}{\lambda^{unboosted}_{\gamma_1}} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}$

we get the expression of the wavelength change by the [relativistic Doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Motion_along_the_line_of_sight) (the difference in the sign of $\beta$ is due to the velocity sign convention).

Answer (score 1):

(This is a qualitative approach only, but I'll give enough data so that you can solve it for yourself)
Alright. The main issue here is that we are neglecting relativisticc effects, which HAVE to be taken into account while dealing with the doppler effect of light.

In the doppler effect of sound, we always assume the medium as a 'rest frame', as sound has a fixed speed relative to its medium. The doppler effect comes partially from this fact. Now, as light has a fixed vacuum speed, in this situation, a rest frame has no meaning. There still *is* a doppler effect, it is known as the [relativistic doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect). As with all relativistic things, this is only significant at large velocities. But the paradox is resolved at whatever velocity you take, as long as we do not neglect this and one more thing:

The momentum of a body in relativity is $\gamma m_0 v$, where $\gamma$ is the lorentz factor, and $m_0$ is the rest mass. Note that the rest mass is the total *energy* of the body at rest divided by $c^2$. Now, as the body loses thermal energy (it's cooling), this value of $m_0$ also decreases. Thus $\gamma m_0$ decreases (by a small amount, unless v is large)

Now, the conjunction of the two gives us this: The momentum of the body decreases, but so does its mass. This should hopefully lead to no net slowing down.
The reason for it not slowing down was well given by @zephyr above. I'll just elaborate it here: Consider a different reference frame, moving with velocity 2v forwards. Now, in this frame, the situation is identical except that the body is moving backwards. Let us assume that it slows down in our initial frame. As all inertial frames are equivalent, it should slow down relative to the new frame, too. But, this slowing down will be in an opposite direction, and thus the two observers will disagree on the direction of the body's deceleration. This is not permitted in inertial frames. So by reducto ad absurdum, the initial premise(the body decelerates) is false. To prove it another way, Just draw a diagram with the velocities and relative velocities and you'll get $-a=a\implies a=0$

Of course, you can quantitatively calculate the change in rest mass and momentum and (hopefully) prove that the the velocity does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The body will not slow down - that would contradict relativity. While the following phrase in the answer: "The body emits radiation based on its temperature" is technically correct, that does not mean that the radiation energy distribution is the same for a moving body and a body at rest. For the moving body you should use electrodynamics of moving bodies.

Answer (score -1):

Lets see.

A photon carries off momentum $h\nu/c$.

Now if the body is a round body, a star lets say, it will be radiating uniformly from the surface. Lets take the forward going ones, their $\nu$ increases due to the forward motion, and the momentum increases. If we take the backward going ones the $\nu$ decreases and the momentum decreases. One would have to [compute it](http://www.astronomynotes.com/starprop/s8.htm), I would say that the forward and backward going momenta will add up to zero change for the body, at first order since they are linear with the wavelength changes, thus not changing the velocity of the body. Calculating for a particular shape and a particular radiation spectrum might give higher order effects .

Comment: If absolute value of the momentum of the photons going forwards is greater than that of photons going backwards, how can they sum up to zero?

Comment: I guess I am saying that a photon of momentum p leaving in front gains from the motion a +delta(p)  and a photon of momentum p leaving behind gets a -delta(p) so the momentum of the body is not affected by the radiation of these two photons.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from ignoring the body. The forward going photons have more momentum and the backward going ones less to the amount the forward took off, leaving the body at the same momentum. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Due to Doppler effect their moments cannot be equal in absolute value.

Comment: Maybe I am explaining badly. The doppler effect affects both forward and backward ones. The forward ones gain, the backward ones lose momentum. The ones going forward gain an amount of momentum that is lost effectively from the ones going backwards, to first order, and leave the body at the same momentum, which was the question asked.

Comment: Those going forward gain in the absolute value of momentum and those going backaward loose in absolute value of momentum, but the both deltas directed to the same direction (forward), so they both effectively slow down the body's motion. Write the formulas down to see yourself. You forgot that momentum is a vector value, not scalar like kinetic energy.